# Google Drive credentials

Tags: google-drive-api

I am creating a app where in i have to store files in Google drive of the user logged in , so which ever user logged in he can store data on his drive. Now i have a problem how to generate  Google Drive credentials (clientId, clientSecret and refreshToken) from code , as all the example i see ,ask as to go to Google console and do that.Is there any we can achieve it using java code. Actually i need to use google drive ad database storage.
Used the below code : but that need the Client id.

```
    public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String clientId = "...";
    String clientSecret = "...";

    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
      httpTransport, 
      jsonFactory,
      clientId,
      clientSecret,
      Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE)
    )
      .setAccessType("online")
      .setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();

    String redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";     
    String url = 
      flow
        .newAuthorizationUrl()
        .setRedirectUri(redirectUri)
        .build();

    System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your browser then type the authorization code:");
    System.out.println("  " + url);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String code = br.readLine();

    GoogleTokenResponse response = 
      flow
        .newTokenRequest(code)
        .setRedirectUri(redirectUri)
        .execute();

    GoogleCredential credential = 
      new GoogleCredential()
        .setFromTokenResponse(response);

    Drive service = 
      new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .build();

    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To obtain client ID and a Client Secret you need to first create or select a project in the Google Developers Console and enable the API.

You can follow the following link:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. To get client id, You need first to go to google developer console from below link https://console.developers.google.com/  .
2. Click on create project and fill the name of project .
3. click APIs & AUTH, after that click on credentials here you will see create new client id  link. Here you get the client id